# Adding headers to email sent as a Laravel Notification

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-notification

Someone knows how to add headers to emails sent through [Laravel Notification System](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#mail-notifications)?

I am not talking about [Mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail) classes where I can set header through the `withSwiftMessage()` method!

I also would like to keep using the `MailMessage` once I have a lot of emails built using the `line`, `greetings` methods!

Any one has any clue?

There is my code in case somebody needs to see anything!

```php
<?php

namespace PumpMyLead\Notifications\Tenants\Auth;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class AccountActivation extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('My email subject')
            ->greeting('Just a greeting')
            ->line('Line 1')
            ->line('Line 2')
            ->action('CTA wanted', 'http://www.pumpmylead.com')
            ->line('Byebye');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually I've found 2 ways to append headers.

When the notification is sent via mail channel an `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending` event is fired.

Append a listener to it. In `handle()` you will get the `Swift_Message` object.

Or in the `AppServiceProvider`'s `register()` method override the `MailChannel` with your own and append the header in the `send()` method.

```
$this->app->bind(
    \Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel::class,
    MyMailChannel::class
);
```

Comment: Thanks, the event listener looks like the easiest way to add header and keep using simple notifications

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modern 2022 alternative if the above doesn't work, tested in Laravel 8.

using `withSwiftMessage()`

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject($subject)
        ->greeting($greeting)
        ->line($line1)
        ->line($line2)
        ->withSwiftMessage(function($message) use ($value1, $value2) {
            $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MJ-CustomID', json_encode([
                'key1' => $value1,
                'key2' => $value2,
            ]));
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In ./app/Notifications/myNotification.php, add this code in your __construct() function:

```
$this->callbacks[]=( function($message){
    $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('x-mailgun-native-send', 'true');
});
```

Replace the "x-mailgun-native-send" with any header you wish to add, 
and 'true' with the desired value.

See  https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/475

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 5.7... The callbacks won't get called.

Comment: Because `callbacks` is a property of `Mailable`, not a property of `Notification`

Comment: The linked laravel ideas issue was merged for laravel 5.8, not 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Debbie V has a pretty close answer but not quite right. The issue she is referencing makes it clear, but she missed the necessary context that solution provided.

By default a Notification in Laravel uses `MailMessage`, however you can also have it return a `Mailable` instead. Only if you: a) create a custom mailable, and b) use that instead of `MailMessage` will the callbacks be applied.

A more complete solution would be:

1. Create a custom mailable class `php artisan make:mail MyMailable`
2. Update your `public function toMail($notifiable)` method to utilize a the new `Mailable`.
3. Add the callbacks to the constructor of your `MyMailable` class.

And after that you should be all good. The hardest part of this is just adapting the current `MailMessage` you use to fit the API of a `Mailable`.